# Probability when considering multiple independence

Tags: probability

I'm stuck on the following question and was wondering if anyone could give me some advice:

"In October 1994 a flaw in a Pentium chip was discovered that could result in a wrong answer when performing division. The manufacturer initially claimed that the chance of any particular division being incorrect was only 1 in 9 billion. Assuming that the 1 in 9 billion figure is correct and that results of different divisions are independent of one another, what is the probability that at least one error occurs in one billion divisions with this chip?"

The following is what I currently have, but I'm not sure if this is right and would appreciate if someone can tell me if I'm doing this incorrectly and how to approach the problem if so.

```
P(one division) = 1/9,000,000,000
P(one error in 1 billion divisions) = 1,000,000,000 * (1/9,000,000,000) = 0.11
```

EDIT:

```
P(at least one error in 1 billion runs) = 1 - [(9 bill - 1)/9 bill]^1bill
P(no errors) = [(9 bill - 1)/9 bill]^1bill
```

Comment: keep in mind the question asks for the probability of "at least one"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: an analogous problem is what is the chance of rolling at least one 6 on 10 dice rolls? This is 1 $-$ the chance of rolling no 6s on 10 dice rolls = $1-(5/6)^{10}$. Taking $5/6$ to the tenth power is because each dice roll is independent and with independence the probabilities multiply.

Adopting your logic on the dice roll problem, the chance of rolling at least one 6 in 10 dice rolls would be $10\times 1/6 = 10/6 > 1$, and you can't have a probability $>1$. In your case, think about what your approach would lead to if the question were for 10 bilion divisions.

You can *multiply* probabilities of events when they are *independent*. You can *add* probabilities of events when they are *mutually exclusive*. But rolling a 6 on one dice roll isn't exclusive with rolling a 6 on another, so you can't add these probabilities (you'd overcount the case where you rolled two 6s). Similarly your approach of adding the probability of an error on one division with an error on another is incorrect because the errors are not mutually exclusive (you overcount the case where more than one error occurs).

Comment: Oh I should of thought of something like that! So in my case it would be something like 1 - (1 / 9bill)^1 bill. This would be less than 1.

Comment: nearly, but if this was correct then it would be $1-(1/6)^{10}$ in the dice roll case.

Comment: Hmmm... So the 5/6 in the dice example is because of the independence in each roll. In my case would what I have posted in my original post (the 0.11) have anything to do with the independence and probabilities multiplying? So something like 1 - (.11)^1bill or am I mixing things up?

Comment: In the dice case we turned the problem round, so we have 1 $-$ the chance of never rolling a 6, and independence allows us to multiply these probabilities together. The 5 out of 6 is because 5 times out of 6 we don't roll a 6. The 6 in the dice rolling case corresponds to a division failure in yours. So if the chance not rolling a 6 is 5/6 the chance of not having a division failure is what in your case? (I'm also going to edit my post to make it clear _why_ you can't take your original approach, beyond the fact it gives probability > 1 if you go on for long enough)

Comment: I see what you mean, so in my case it would be (8,999,999,999 / 9 bill) the chance that there isn't a failure. But since there's 1 billion attempts (almost like 1 billion dice rolls) it's [(9 bill - 1)/9 bill]^1 bill the chance that there wouldn't be a failure in 1 billion attempts

Comment: yes exactly. My only concern is that if you fed that into a calculator there might be some precision errors because (1-9 billion)/(9 billion) is a lot of 9s, but that's a whole nother issue :)

Comment: I'm more concerned with understanding the concept instead of calculating the correct answer on the calculator. :) This makes a lot more sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> P(no errors in 1 billion runs) = 1 - [(9 bill - 1)/9 bill]^1bill
>
> P(at least one error) = 1 - answer above

As you previously mentioned, [(9 bill - 1)/9 bill]^1 bill is the chance that there is no failure in one billion divisions. One minus that is the probability of at least one failure, exactly like in the case of rolling the die. Why subtract that result from one again?

Comment: Typo, thanks for pointing it out tho